# Track number of status changes by an instance

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I need to track how one customer changes from one state to another, and keep track of its actions in each state. I have the following table:

```
Name - Purchase_date - Customer_category
Susan - 01_01_2021 - A
Susan - 02_01_2021 - B
Susan - 03_01_2021 - B
Susan - 04_01_2021 - B
Susan - 05_01_2021 - B
Susan - 06_01_2021 - A
Susan - 07_01_2021 - A
Susan - 08_01_2021 - B
Susan - 09_01_2021 - B
Susan - 10_01_2021 - B
Susan - 11_01_2021 - C
Susan - 12_01_2021 - D
```

Expected result is a table with two additional rows, *category_switch_number* and *occurences_number*, where *category_switch_number* shows which switch is it for this particular customer (counting from 1), and *occurences_number* shows number of purchases made, when customer was in this category:

```
Name - Purchase_date - Customer_category - category_switch_number - occurences_number
Susan - 01_01_2021 - A - 1 - 1
Susan - 02_01_2021 - B - 2 - 4
Susan - 03_01_2021 - B - 2 - 4
Susan - 04_01_2021 - B - 2 - 4
Susan - 05_01_2021 - B - 2 - 4
Susan - 06_01_2021 - A - 3 - 2
Susan - 07_01_2021 - A - 3 - 2
Susan - 08_01_2021 - B - 4 - 3
Susan - 09_01_2021 - B - 4 - 3
Susan - 10_01_2021 - B - 4 - 3
Susan - 11_01_2021 - C - 5 - 1
Susan - 12_01_2021 - D - 6 - 1
```

To copy this table and try running the query yourself see the table creation statement below:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Customer_id` varchar(5), `purchase_time` varchar(10), `Customer_category` varchar(1), `category_switch_number` int, `occurences_number` int)
GO
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Customer_id`, `purchase_time`, `Customer_category`, `category_switch_number`, `occurences_number`)
VALUES
    ('Susan', '01_01_2021', 'A', 1, 1),
    ('Susan', '02_01_2021', 'B', 2, 4),
    ('Susan', '03_01_2021', 'B', 2, 4),
    ('Susan', '04_01_2021', 'B', 2, 4),
    ('Susan', '05_01_2021', 'B', 2, 4),
    ('Susan', '06_01_2021', 'A', 3, 2),
    ('Susan', '07_01_2021', 'A', 3, 2),
    ('Susan', '08_01_2021', 'B', 4, 3),
    ('Susan', '09_01_2021', 'B', 4, 3),
    ('Susan', '10_01_2021', 'B', 4, 3),
    ('Susan', '11_01_2021', 'C', 5, 1),
    ('Susan', '12_01_2021', 'D', 6, 1)
GO
```

I apologise for not sharing what I have tried, as with code examples (that I find more useful) this post is already big, but showing what I have tried will make it even bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1
Create a cte with a window function to find the customer's prior purchase category based on purchase time.

Step 2
Using the cte from step 1, create a grouping of each of the sequences where the customer category is the same from one purchase date to the next. When the customer category changes, increment that sequence grouping. This is accomplished by using a running sum window function.

Step 3
Using the cte from step 2, using a final count() window function for the customer and sequence grouping, which will count the consecutive times that the customer has been in that catgory.

```
with priors as (
  select t.*
    , lag(t.customer_category) over(partition by t.customer_id order by t.purchase_time) as prior_category
  from Table1 t
 ),
 
  
 category_seq_grps as (
   select t2.*
    , sum(case when t2.prior_category = t2.customer_category then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by  t2.customer_id order by t2.purchase_time rows unbounded preceding) as cust_cat_seq_grouping
   from priors t2
   )


 select csg.customer_id
    , csg.purchase_time
    , csg.customer_category
    , csg.cust_cat_seq_grouping as category_switch_number
    , count(*) over(partition by csg.customer_id,    csg.cust_cat_seq_grouping) as occurences_number
 from category_seq_grps csg
 order by csg.customer_id
    , csg.purchase_time
;
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate. Thanks for including the data, results and DDL for your question.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8er78RNugk9TWQPzx5xdXP/1